# Display subcategory and its parent category in a table from single mysql database table using php

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, pdo

This is my database table

| id | category | parent_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | category1 |  |
| 2 | category2 |  |
| 3 | category3 |  |
| 4 | subcategory4 | 2 |
| 5 | subcategory5 | 1 |
| 6 | subcategory6 | 3 |
| 7 | subcategory7 | 1 |

This is my code

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM category_table ORDER BY parent_id");
    
    $category = array(
    'categories' => array(),
    'parent_cats' => array()
    );
    
    //build the array lists with data from the category table
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    //creates entry into categories array with current category id ie. $categories['categories'][1]
    $category['categories'][$row['id']] = $row;
    //creates entry into parent_cats array. parent_cats array contains a list of all categories with children
    $category['parent_cats'][$row['parent_id']][] = $row['id'];
                                                                }
    
    function buildCategory($parent, $category) {
    $html = "";
    if (isset($category['parent_cats'][$parent])) {
        
        foreach ($category['parent_cats'][$parent] as $cat_id) {
            if (!isset($category['parent_cats'][$cat_id])) {
                $html .= "<tr>\n";
                $html .= "<td>\n  <a href=''>" . $category['categories'][$cat_id]['category'] . "</a>\n</td> \n";
                $html .= "</tr>\n";
            }
            if (isset($category['parent_cats'][$cat_id])) {
                $html .= "<tr>\n";
                $html .= "<td>\n  <a href=''>" . $category['categories'][$cat_id]['category'] . "</a> \n";
                $html .= buildCategory($cat_id, $category);
                $html .= "</td> \n";
                $html .= "</tr>\n";
            }
        }
        
    }
    return $html;
    }
    
    
    echo buildCategory('', $category);?>
```

Output for above code looks like:

| category1 |
| --- |
| subcategory5 |
| subcategory7 |

| category2 |
| --- |
| subcategory4 |

| category3 |
| --- |
| subcategory6 |

My expected output should look like this:

| category | Parent Category |
| --- | --- |
| category1 |  |
| category2 |  |
| category3 |  |
| subcategory5 | category1 |
| subcategory7 | category1 |
| subcategory4 | category2 |
| subcategory6 | category3 |

I have been working on this for a while now.. Can anyone please tell me how can I modify my code or use any other method to achieve my expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query instead inner join will give you only the required data,
then you can adjust the data as per your needs.

```
SELECT sub_category.id as s_id, sub_category.category as s_cat_name, p_category.category as p_cat_name 
FROM category_table sub_category 
INNER JOIN category_table p_category ON p_category.id = sub_category.parent_id 
ORDER BY sub_category.id
```

**Update on how can this be used in code,**
Try this,

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT sub_category.id as s_id, sub_category.category as s_cat_name, p_category.category as p_cat_name FROM category_table sub_category INNER JOIN category_table p_category ON p_category.id = sub_category.parent_id ORDER BY sub_category.id");
    
$html = "<tr><th>Category Id</th><th>Category Name</th><th>Parent Category</th></tr>";

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

            $html .= "<tr>";
            $html .= "<td>".$row['s_id']."</td>";
            $html .= "<td>".$row['s_cat_name']."</td>";
            $html .= "<td>".$row['p_cat_name ']."</td>";
            $html .= "</tr>";          
}
    
echo $html;
```

Comment: Thanks.. I got the mysql query.. But I am not getting how to modify my php code for this query

Comment: @user_59910105 are you still looking for a solution, if yes I can update my answer and that might help you out

Comment: Yes I am still looking for  the solution

Comment: Check the updated code and let me know if it works